# delete tableView cell, and remove data from firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

I'm new to swift and firebase. Done some research here, could not find solution that would solve my problem, lack of experience.

Got a problem when trying to delete tableView Cell from firebase "Value of type 'Group' has no member 'ref'"

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let ref = groupsArray[indexPath.row].ref
        ref!.removeValue()
        groupsArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
}}
```

[image]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
[image]

TAbleView

```
    extension ChatViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return groupsArray.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = groupsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "groupTableViewCell", for:indexPath) as?
        GroupTableViewCell else {return UITableViewCell()}
    let group = groupsArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.configureCell(title: group.groupTitle, description: group.groupDesc, membersCount: group.membersCount)
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let groupFeedViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GroupFeedViewController") as? GroupFeedViewController else {return}
    groupFeedViewController.initData(forGroup: groupsArray[indexPath.row])
    presentDetail(groupFeedViewController)

}}
```

Group Class

```
    import Foundation

    class Group {
private var _groupTitle: String
private var _groupDesc: String
private var _key: String
private var _memberCount: Int
private var _members: [String]

var groupTitle: String {
    return _groupTitle
}

var groupDesc: String {
   return _groupDesc
}
var key: String {
    return _key
}
var membersCount: Int {
    return _memberCount
}
var members: [String] {
    return _members
}

init(title: String, description: String, key: String, members: [String], memberCount: Int){
    self._groupTitle = title
    self._groupDesc = description
    self._key = key
    self._members = members
    self._memberCount = memberCount
}}
```

Comment: Please post the code that populates the tableview.  You may only need to delete the data from firebase and the tableview will update automatically.

Comment: "delete tableView cell from firebase"  It does not make any right-mind sense.

Comment: edited, sorry about badly former question.

Comment: @rMickeyD Added the code at the top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't delete a `tableViewCell` from Firebase, but you can remove the data from Firebase that you pull to populate your `tableView`.

Second, what you're doing wrong is trying to get a class value of `ref` from an array.

Third, after deleting the data from the web, you'll still need to remove the cell from the table which your code looks like it will do just fine but I'm putting it here for completeness.

> To delete a value from Firebase you need to create a reference and then process things from there. Like this :

```
let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: yourProjectURL)
let groupRef= ref.child("groups").child(groupsArray[indexPath.row].key)
// ^^ this only works if the value is set to the firebase uid, otherwise you need to pull that data from somewhere else.
groupRef.removeValue()
```

> Then delete the item from the array:

```
groupsArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
```

> And delete the row from the `tableView`:

```
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
```

> Everything should look like this :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: yourProjectURL)
        let groupRef= ref.child("groups").child(groupsArray[indexPath.row].key)
        // ^^ this only works if the value is set to the firebase uid, otherwise you need to pull that data from somewhere else.
        groupRef.removeValue()
        groupsArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this value supposed to be? `groupsArray[indexPath.row]`

Comment: so I did what you have said, and unfortunately that did not help me, now application crashes with error "reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0."

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the code to this function `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)`

Comment: if I do post the code to function that you mentioned I get unresolved indexPath identifier

Comment: Can you post what your `groupsArray` holds?

Comment: var groupsArray = [Group]()

Comment: Please update your code to display what your `Group` Object is

Comment: @basis where did you get `L6v5X28jvcxJKCz0Q5` from? How did Firebase come to store that value? Is that Group.key?

Comment: oh  `private var _REF_GROUPS = DB_BASE.child("groups")`.                           `var REF_GROUPS: DatabaseReference{
        return _REF_GROUPS
    }`                                                                                                          `func createGroup(withTitle title: String, andDescription description: String, forUserIds ids: [String], handler: @escaping (_ groupCreated: Bool) ->()) {
        REF_GROUPS.childByAutoId().updateChildValues(["title": title, "description": description, "members": ids])
        handler(true)
    }` newbie to stack and to programming

Comment: ... That doesn't really answer my question. But I assume that it came from Group.key and I've updated my answer for that scenario. Please copy and paste the last bit of code in my answer and try again. If that doesn't work please EXPLAIN where the value `L6v5X28jvcxJKCz0Q5` came from.

Comment: I can't thank you enough .key at the end worked and it deleted data from firebase. thank you ever so much, you deserve a medal sir.

Comment: Happy to help. It takes a while before this stuff clicks but you’re on the right track. If I might suggest changing your class to something more concise and just changing the `private var` to plain `var` so you don’t need to add the variable return statements. No point in private If you end up making them public

Comment: As you suggested I've changed them not to be private and thank you again