# How to delete tableView cell and remove data from firebase

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Stuck, trying to swipe left on an event so that it deletes from the TableView and deletes from Firebase real-time-database. This is what I have so far. Stuck on implementing so that it goes with my working project.

[Firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSbKR.png)

Table View

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: yourProjectURL)
        let eventRef = ref.child("events").child(postEvents[indexPath.row].key)
        // ^^ this only works if the value is set to the firebase uid, otherwise you need to pull that data from somewhere else.
        postEvents.removeValue()
        postEvents.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}
```

what goes in ".reference(fromURL: yourProjectURL)" for me? is It ->  .child("events")

Event Class

```
struct Events {

let eventId: String
let eventName: String
let city: String
let state: String
let country: String
let startDate: String
let endDate: String
let itinerary: String
let isPrivate: Bool
var members: [String]
var isJoined : Bool
let creator : String

init?(eventId: String, dict: [String: Any]) {

    //let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    //dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +zzzz"

    guard let eventName = dict["eventName"] as? String,
        let city = dict["city"] as? String,
        let country = dict["country"] as? String,
        let state = dict["state"] as? String,
        let startDate = dict["startDate"] as? String,
        let endDate = dict["endDate"] as? String,
        let itinerary = dict["itinerary"] as? String,
        let creator = dict["creator"] as? String,
        let eventType = dict["eventType"] as? String

        else { return nil }

    self.eventName = eventName
    self.city = city
    self.country = country
    self.state = state
    self.startDate = startDate
    self.endDate = endDate
    self.itinerary = itinerary
    self.isPrivate = eventType == "private" ? true : false
    self.eventId = eventId
    var members = [String]()
    if let dic = dict["members"] as? [String:String] {
        for (_,value) in dic {
            members.append(value)
        }
    }
    self.isJoined =  members.contains(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
    self.members = members
    self.creator = creator

}}
```

On postEvents.removeValue() I get an error "Value of type '[Events]' has no member 'removeValue'". How do I fix that?

Comment: Appreciate the help in advance

Comment: Would like to mention I tried using this for help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49437793/delete-tableview-cell-and-remove-data-from-firebase

Comment: Please don’t include images or links in your questions. Include code and structures as text (for firestore structures, image is ok) so we can use them in answers with copy/paste. If need to include an image, please include it in the question, not a link. Over time, links can break and if they do, future readers wont have access to that info which could invalidate the question.

Comment: It's unclear what the code in `if editingStyle == .delete ` is supposed to do. What should happen is 1) get the index of the row being deleted 2) in your tableView datasource (usually an array) get the object at that index 3) Get the Firebase key from that object 4) Delete it from firebase and then remove from your dataSource. 5) reload your tableView or remove the row from the UI if you're using animations. Note this will a bit different if you're observing the data in Firebase as in that case, delete from firebase and handle the rest within the Firebase observer function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete a node in Firebase, first establish the path to that node by creating a reference to it, and then removeValue on that reference (or set the ref to nil which also removes it)

In brief

```
let eventToDelete = dataSource[indexPath.row] //get the event from the dataSource
let firebaseKey = eventToDelete.eventId //assuming the eventId is the node key
let eventRef = my_firebase.child("events").child(firebaseKey)
eventRef.removeValue()  //or eventRef.setValue(nil)
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me out!

Comment: How would I be able to wrap this with UIAlert controller, so when they swipe and click on collect a box appears to make sure they want to delete or not.